# Sqlfiddle problems

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

```
Create table customer
(CustomerID int(255) not null auto_increment,
FirstName varchar(255) not null,
LastName varchar(255) not null,
StreetAddress char(255) not null,
Apartment varchar(255) not null,
City varchar(255) not null,
State varchar(2) not null,
ZipCode int(9) not null,
HomePhone int(10) not null,
MobilePhone int(10) not null,
OtherPhone int(10) not null,
Primary Key (CustomerID));
insert into Customer 
(FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, Apartment, City, State,
ZipCode, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone)
Values ("Ken", "Weger", "StreetAddress", "Apartment", "City", 
"ST", 123456789, 1111111111, 222222222, 333333333);

Create Table Doughnut
(DoughnutID int(255) not null auto_increment,
Name varchar(255) not null,
Description varchar(255) not null,
UnitPrice decimal(3,2) not null,
Primary Key (DoughnutID));
insert into Doughnut (Name, Description, UnitPrice)
Values ("Plain", "Plain Donut", "1.50"),
("Glazed", "Glazed Donut", "1.75"),
("Cinnamon", "Cinnamon Donut", "1.75"),
("Chocolate", "Chocolate Donut", "1.75"),
("Sprinkle", "Sprinkle Donut", "1.75"),
("Gluten-Free", "Gluten-Free Donut", "2.00");

Create Table DoughnutOrder
(DoughnutOrderID int(255) not null auto_increment,
DoughnutID int(255),
Quantity int(255),
Primary Key (DoughnutOrderID),
Index Doughnut(doughnutid),
Foreign Key (DoughnutID) References Doughnut(DoughnutID));
Insert into Doughnutorder (DoughnutId, Quantity)
values ((select DoughnutId from Doughnut where doughnutid = 1), 1),
      ((select DoughnutId from Doughnut where doughnutid = 2), 5),
      ((select DoughnutId from Doughnut where doughnutid = 3), 12),
       ((select DoughnutId from Doughnut where doughnutid = 4), 3),
       ((select DoughnutId from Doughnut where doughnutid = 5), 4),
        ((select DoughnutId from Doughnut where doughnutid =6), 5);

Create Table Sales
(ORDERID int(255) not null Auto-increment,
CustomerID int(255) not null,
DoughnutOrderID int(255) not null,
`Date` date not null,
SpecialHandlingInstructions varchar(255),
Primary Key (ORDERID),
Index Customer (customerID),
Foreign Key (customerid) References customer(customerid),
Index doughnutorder (doughnutorderid),
Foreign Key (doughnutorderid) references doughnutorder(doughnutorderid);

 Insert into Sales (Customerid, DoughnutorderID, `date`, SpecialHandlingInstructions)
Values ((select customerid from customer), (select DoughnutOrderID from DoughnutOrder), 20151104, Please Include plates and napkins);
```

I am working with this on sqlfiddle. It tells me schema is ready but each time i do a simple

```
Select * from Sales;
```

I get the response table sales doesn't exist. Any Ideas as to why? I am only doing it on this site because it is where my school wants me to take the screenshots from to show that the code works.

Comment: I believe my error that is causing the table to not be created is in the code for the create table sales section. I have made so many changes but i can never come back with a good result. can anyone see a problem i am not seeing in that section of code.

Comment: SQLFiddle crashes very often recently.. doesn't display results for simple `SELECT`s as you have pointed out, doesn't manage to connect to the db driver etc... (*it used to be more stable about a year ago, i don't think you can blame your code*)

Comment: well that bites this is a project for school and i have to provide screenshots from sqlfiddle showing it working. i have already sent a message to the administrators of the sight about constant crashes i have been getting.

Answer (score 0):

## Schema

```
Create table customer
(
CustomerID int(255) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
FirstName varchar(255) not null,
LastName varchar(255) not null,
StreetAddress char(255) not null,
Apartment varchar(255) not null,
City varchar(255) not null,
State varchar(2) not null,
ZipCode int(9) not null,
HomePhone int(10) not null,
MobilePhone int(10) not null,
OtherPhone int(10) not null,
Primary Key (CustomerID)
);

insert into Customer 
(FirstName, LastName, StreetAddress, Apartment, City, State,
ZipCode, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone)
Values ("Ken", "Weger", "StreetAddress", "Apartment", "City", 
"ST", 123456789, 1111111111, 222222222, 333333333);

Create Table Doughnut
(DoughnutID int(255) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
Name varchar(255) not null,
Description varchar(255) not null,
UnitPrice decimal(3,2) not null,
Primary Key (DoughnutID)
);

insert into Doughnut (Name, Description, UnitPrice)
Values ("Plain", "Plain Donut", "1.50"),
("Glazed", "Glazed Donut", "1.75"),
("Cinnamon", "Cinnamon Donut", "1.75"),
("Chocolate", "Chocolate Donut", "1.75"),
("Sprinkle", "Sprinkle Donut", "1.75"),
("Gluten-Free", "Gluten-Free Donut", "2.00");


Create Table DoughnutOrder
(DoughnutOrderID int(255) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
DoughnutID int(255),
Quantity int(255),
Primary Key (DoughnutOrderID),
Index Doughnut(doughnutid),
Foreign Key (DoughnutID) References Doughnut(DoughnutID));

Insert into Doughnutorder (DoughnutId, Quantity)
values (1, 1),
(2, 5),
(3, 12),
(4, 3),
(5, 4),
(6, 5);

Create Table Sales
(
ORDERID int(255) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
CustomerID int(255) not null,
DoughnutOrderID int(255) not null,
`Date` date not null,
SpecialHandlingInstructions varchar(255),
Primary Key (ORDERID),
Index Customer (customerID),
Foreign Key (customerid) References customer(customerid),
Index doughnutorder (doughnutorderid),
Foreign Key (doughnutorderid) references doughnutorder(doughnutorderid)
);


Insert into Sales (Customerid, DoughnutorderID, `date`, SpecialHandlingInstructions)
Values (1, 1, 20151104, 'Please Include plates and napkins');
```

## SQL Statement

```
Select * from Sales;
```

## Result

```
+-------+----------+---------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
|ORDERID|CustomerID|DoughnutOrderID|Date                      |SpecialHandlingInstructions                   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1      |1         |1              |November, 04 2015 00:00:00|Please Include plates and napkins
```